# Checking grandchildren records to return grand-parent. Linq

Tags: linq, .net-core, iqueryable

I have different roles and each user can have multiple roles. Each role is connected to customer record in different way, e.g. a business analyst has many-to-many relation to project and each customer has many projects; whereas a customer record can have only one project manager associated to it.

```
public class Customer
{
    public CustomerProjectManager ProjectManager { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects{ get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Project 
{
    public ICollection<ProjectBusinessAnalyst> BusinessAnalysts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectDeveloper> ProjectDevelopers { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ProjectDeveloper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string DeveloperId { get; set; }
    public string DeveloperEmail { get; set; }
    public string DeveloperName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerProjectManager
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
     public string ProjectManagerId { get; set; }
     public string ProjectManagerEmail { get; set; }
     public string ProjectManagerName { get; set; }

     public CustomerProjectManager()
     {
         Customers = new List<Customer>();
     }
}
```

I need to fetch customer records on basis of roles. To explain further, I need to combine multiple customer lists fetched on the basis of different roles assigned to a single user. I am unable to form right linq query.

I have a sample query, mentioned below, which sometimes returns the right records but if I have a new user and no customers are assigned to this user, the query returns all existing customers. Its important for me that all the combination and filtration is done in Iqueryable

Please help!

```
public async Task<List<Customer>> FetchCustomers(string userId, List<string> userRoles, string userEmail)
{
    if (userRoles.Contains("Admin"))
    {
         customer = _context.Customers;
    }
    else if (userRoles.Contains("Project Manager") ||
             userRoles.Contains("Business Analyst") ||
             userRoles.Contains("Developer"))
    {
         if (userRoles.Contains("Project Manager"))
         {
             customers = customers.Where(c => c.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerId == userId
                       || c.Projects.Any(op =>                                              
                          op.ProjectsCompleted.Any(assignee =>                                                           
                          assignee.UserId == userId)));
         }
         if (userRoles.Contains("Business Analyst"))
         {
             var allPossibleCustomers = _context.Customers.Where(c =>
                            c.Projects.Any(op => op.BusinessAnalysts.Any(ba => ba.BusinessAnalystId == userId)));

             customers = customers?.Union(allPossibleCustomers) ?? allPossibleCustomers;
         }
         if (userRoles.Contains(Roles.Developer.GetDescription()))
         {
              var allPossibleCustomers = _context.Customers.Where(c =>
              c.Projects.Any(op => op.PREDevDevelopersAssigned.Any(ba => ba.DeveloperId == userId)));
                    
             customers = customers?.Union(allPossibleCustomers) ?? allPossibleCustomers;
         }
    }
    var listData = await PagingList<Customer>.CreatePageAsync(customers, page, limit);
    return listData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was trying to return the wrong list. The linq query is correct.